# Mongodb graphQL and Feather js data fetch by _id return null for some case

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, feathersjs

I'm trying to fetch records on the basis of _id in mongoDB, In mongoDB console it working fine, but when I try to implement the same code in GraphQL and Feather js, it returns null, record not found, but records is in DB. If i change the value to `507F191M810c19729De860eA` is return record. It works for a few values. It's a very Weird issue.

```
Locations.find(
      { 
        query: 
        { 
          _id: "2313891acb3420defAFadefc" 
        }
      }
    ).then(function(result){
      console.log(result)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try ti find mongoId by convert into objcectId. You are passing id as a simple string. May be you are not getting the data.

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Now you can convert string into mongo's id.

```
Locations.find(
  { 
    Query: 
    { 
      _id: ObjectID("2313891acb3420defAFadefc") 
    }
  }
).then(function(result){
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Already, I tried not working, I stored the values in string format, not an object. It is very strange it works for a few ids.

Comment: I suggest you to never store mongoID in a string. When you want to fire aggregate you will face ID issue.

Comment: And can you please try to find this id in robo 3t or in shell?

Comment: but when i try to implement using graphQL and feather js, it return null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184575/discussion-between-chandan-kumar-and-sachin-shah).

Comment: but y, whts the difference between query and Query

Comment: @ChandanKumar I really don't know , it may be the syntax of it. I have just do small RND and I found that they used `Query` .